# How to replace a value in a list with other value in a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, replace, tuples

Assume that I have a list:

```
a = [26, 54, 108, 156, 166, 1]
```

And I also have some other list that is variable which is a list with tuple inside:

```
b02 b05 b10 b15 b16 b00
```

I want to get this list:

```
b = [b02[6][1], b05[4][1], b10[8][1], b15[6][1], b00[1][1]]
```

That tha value in a replace with the value that their ten and hundreds digit is equal to the number after `b`, and their digit equals to the `[digit]` value of 
`b`

I first defined a function to get their digit number

```
def get_digit(number, n):
    return number // 10**n % 10
```

How to get `b`?

Answer (score 0):

I would first put all the `b*` lists in a `dict` so you can look them up properly:

```
b_lists = {
    2: b02,
    5: b05,
    10: b10,
    15: b15,
    0: b00,
}
```

Then to map each element the function would be:

```
def map_value(value):
    return b_lists[value // 10][value % 10][1]
```

So the complete mapping would be:

```
b = [map_value(value) for value in a]
```

Or just:

```
b = list(map(map_value, a))
```